# Why does Raphael's framerate slow down on this code?

Tags: raphael

So I'm just doing a basic orbit simulator using Raphael JS, where I draw one circle as the "star" and another circle as the "planet". It seems to be working just fine, with the one snag that as the simulation continues, its framerate progressively slows down until the orbital motion no longer appears fluid. Here's the code (note: uses jQuery only to initialize the page):

```
$(function() {
    var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'), 640, 480);
    var star = paper.circle(320, 240, 10);
    var planet = paper.circle(320, 150, 5);
    var starVelocity = [0,0];
    var planetVelocity = [20.42,0];
    var starMass = 3.08e22;
    var planetMass = 3.303e26;
    var gravConstant = 1.034e-18;
    function calculateOrbit() {
        var accx = 0;
        var accy = 0;
        accx = (gravConstant * starMass * ((star.attr('cx') - planet.attr('cx')))) / (Math.pow(circleDistance(), 3));
        accy = (gravConstant * starMass * ((star.attr('cy') - planet.attr('cy')))) / (Math.pow(circleDistance(), 3));
        planetVelocity[0] += accx;
        planetVelocity[1] += accy;
        planet.animate({cx: planet.attr('cx') + planetVelocity[0], cy: planet.attr('cy') + planetVelocity[1]}, 150, calculateOrbit);
        paper.circle(planet.attr('cx'), planet.attr('cy'), 1); // added to 'trace' orbit
    }
    function circleDistance() {
        return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(star.attr('cx') - planet.attr('cx'), 2) + Math.pow(star.attr('cy') - planet.attr('cy'), 2)));
    }
    calculateOrbit();
});
```

It doesn't appear, to me anyway, that any part of that code would cause the animation to gradually slow down to a crawl, so any help solving the problem will be appreciated!

Comment: I got to this question searching for an answer why my little raphael widget went horribly slow when I didn't really change anything in it. I only plugged in jQuery and use jQuery selectors instead of document.getElementById() calls to access individual widget parts. It seems to me that jQuery can seriously slow things down when combined with Raphael.

Comment: You can improve this now using the 'eve' object added in Raphael, you can then get an update every frame, and do your calculations there, so I would have the planet.animate called once with another function doing the calculations.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the call back to calculateOrbit in your planet.animate() call.  Its not being handled by raphael correctly and is causing a memory leak or an execution slow down.  if you remove it and replace the line

```
calculateOrbit()
```

with

```
setInterval(calculateOrbit, 150);
```

it should run smoothly.

full code:

```
$(function() {
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'), 640, 480);
var star = paper.circle(320, 240, 10);
var planet = paper.circle(320, 150, 5);
var starVelocity = [0,0];
var planetVelocity = [20.42,0];
var starMass = 3.08e22;
var planetMass = 3.303e26;
var gravConstant = 1.034e-18;
function calculateOrbit() {
    var accx = 0;
    var accy = 0;
    accx = (gravConstant * starMass * ((star.attr('cx') - planet.attr('cx')))) / (Math.pow(circleDistance(), 3));
    accy = (gravConstant * starMass * ((star.attr('cy') - planet.attr('cy')))) / (Math.pow(circleDistance(), 3));
    planetVelocity[0] += accx;
    planetVelocity[1] += accy;
    planet.animate({cx: planet.attr('cx') + planetVelocity[0], cy: planet.attr('cy') + planetVelocity[1]}, 150);
    paper.circle(planet.attr('cx'), planet.attr('cy'), 1); // added to 'trace' orbit
}
function circleDistance() {
    return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(star.attr('cx') - planet.attr('cx'), 2) + Math.pow(star.attr('cy') - planet.attr('cy'), 2)));
}
setInterval(calculateOrbit, 150);
});
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and would like to attempt this solution. Can I ask, where did 150 ms come from in your call to setInterval?